# Register custom Jinja2 filter in Pyramid app

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

I have tried this a few ways.  Per [the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_jinja2/en/latest/?awesome#jinja2-filters), I have done this in my app's ini:

```
[app:myapp]
#...
jinja2.filters =
    islist = myapp.machines.islist
```

My function is simply:

```
def islist(item):
    return isinstance(item, list)
```

I can tell the filter setup line in the ini file is being read, because if I get the dotted path to my `islist` function wrong, the app throws an error.

However, when I try to use the `islist` function in a template, the template can't find the function.

```
{% if islist([]) %}a list{% else %}not a list{% endif %}
```

Results in this:

```
UndefinedError: 'islist' is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong??  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think filters are not exposed as functions in the namespace but rather are only invoked via the pipe. For example `{{ foo | some_filter }}`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  So should I be using a test instead?  Can I add custom tests in the same way?  I can't think how I would use an `islist` test as a filter.

Comment: BTW, the filter works..thanks, but again, how can I use it practically?

Comment: Actually no longer need custom `islist` test.  Achieved the same thing with `{% if i is iterable and not i is string and not i is mapping %}` ;)

Comment: The common way to expose functions to your templates within Pyramid is via a `BeforeRender` event or by returning them as part of the payload from your view. The final way would be to access the Jinja2 `Environment` object and add your own "tests" to it through `env.tests['islist'] = islist`.

Comment: Ah of course!  I forgot you can pass functions etc from the view.  That would be the simplest, for sure.  Thanks again!

Comment: I spoke a little prematurely but I think you have enough information to continue. AFAIK tests are not the same as functions in Jinja2 so my final bit of advice may be in error.